# JSON RPC Error code -32000 when deploying on BSCTESTNET with Remix IDE using Metamask

Tags: remix, metamask, json-rpc, pancakeswap, binance

So I wrote a **contract here**:
https://github.com/connova/CareBuds-Finance/blob/main/contracts/Buds.sol

When deploying this using the injected web3 on the binance testnet (network name BSC Testnet) using remix.ethereum.org

I get the following **error**:

> Error  Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below).
> The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force
> sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message":
> "execution reverted" }

When I try force sending, it still fails.

Here is **the failed transaction**: https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xddbe45fe933f8931efe7f355d2e9d261cdad3d9aa8383ef4129259b7609dc222

When deploying using remix I enter these **parameters into the constructor**:

1. *0x53904DaebA21A10262bC460E91aA44B2608dC2BF* (goodBudsWallet)
2. *0x04650Fe3f51B1079fEC3d71b96669857dEa3bBcb* (smokeOutWallet)
3. *["0x04650Fe3f51B1079fEC3d71b96669857dEa3bBcb", "0x10d878297155226C5DbDBB19609D6553981aCc28"]*

#3 is an array of team members (what I actually enter into the constructor as its third parameter when deploying).
These addresses are the accounts I have created in Metamask, none of them are the accounts initiating the contract creation.

What **I've tried**:

- I changed my browser from brave to chrome and had the same error.
- [update] I removed the array input parameter in the constructor, but I still have the exact same error.

Comment: The contract uses an address from bsc chain `0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F` as IUniswapV2Router02 
 router. 

The address exists on testnet but it is not a IUniswapV2Router02 
 router and calling will fail. Look for the correct address for testnet.